# How do I replace </script> to </scr"+"ipt>

Tags: php, javascript

Okay I've something looks like below from user input, known that a `</script>` will not working inside a document.write() function

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='"+(location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + "//www.domain.com/script.js'></script>");</script>
```

Is there anyway to replace the `</script>` to `</scr"+"ipt>` inside document.write() function?

Comment: Where is the difference?

Comment: Yes. `str_replace( '</script>', '</scr"+"ipt>', $string );`

Comment: The right way to escape `</script>` is to escape the slash: `<\/script>`.

Comment: @arnaud576875: Why "right"? It's *one* way to do it, you could escape any of the other characters as well :-)

Comment: @yvytty Because if you have `</script>` inside a JavaScript string, the browser thinks you're closing the script tag.

Comment: @LightStyle, yvytty: Because the HTML parser would close the element on encountering `</script>`, not noticing that it's meant to be inside a string literal

Comment: @Bergi — Right because it avoids a string concatenation operation, is more readable than string concatenation, and `/` is the traditional character to escape in that sequence (so people expect it and won't be trying to figure out why the (for instance) s is escaped)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anyway to replace the `</script>` to `</scr"+"ipt>` inside document.write() function?

No.

The sequence of characters `</script>` is parsed as an end tag by the HTML parser before it even reaches the JavaScript parser.

You have to edit the source code before sending it to the browser.

---

That said, there are better ways to approach the problem then looking a `location.protocol` anyway. Use a scheme relative URI instead:

```
<script src="//www.example.com/script.js'></script>
```

Or redirect all HTTP traffic for the HTML document to HTTPS so that you never serve it on an insecure connection.

---

Your comments suggest that the question you should have asked was:

> How can I place arbitrary submitted form data into a JavaScript string literal using PHP?

Use the `json_encode` function. If you pass it a string, it will give you a JavaScript escaped string suitable for inserting into a `<script>` element. (It won't be a valid JSON Text though, since that must have an object or array at the outermost level).

```
<script>
    document.write(<?php echo json_encode($_POST['script']); ?>);
</script>
```

**Serious security warning**: Do not do this without implementing [protection from CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) as allowing third parties to cause your users to submit JavaScript to your site could be a major problem.

Comment: I think he does something like `document.write(<?php echo $user_input; ?>)` and wants to replace it in PHP --- can't be sure, though.

Comment: I got this `<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='"+(location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + "//www.domain.com/script.js'></script>");</script>` from a textarea which is entered by user, which means that I have no control over what user is going to give me. But, I need to somehow detect if there is a `</script>` inside a document.write() function, and replace it with `</scr"+"ipt>

After that, I'm going to do as below
`<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.write("'.$_POST['input'].'");</script>';`

Comment: @user2424527 — Why are you allowing users to add scripts to the page in the first place? That's likely to cause an enormous XSS security hole.